# Unresolved Reference Error after moving project folder

Tags: android, kotlin

I recently moved my android studio project folder onto usb and when I put it back onto my computer, many objects are red and say 'unresolved reference' such as buttons and kotlinx imports. I also do not get function suggestions when I type such as typing 'button1.' would show a list of suggestions.

Comment: Try to `Invalidate Cache and Restart` or `Clean Build`

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem with my recent android studio.

One of the best solutions to solve this issue is "Invalidate Cache and Restart" and "Sync Project with Gradle files" from the File menu.

[image: Invalidate cache]